# Internet connection problem with second (USB to) Ethernet adapter

Tags: pi-4, ubuntu, internet

we have Raspberry Pi CM4 with Ubuntu. On board ethernet adapter (eth0) is connected to internet and USB to ethernet adapter (eth1) connected a device with a static ip.

When we plug the eth1 internet connection goes away.

Here is our netplan yaml;

```
Network:
    Version: 2
    ethernets:
        eth0:
            dhcp4: true
        eth1:
            dhcp4: false
            addresses: [192.168.5.15/24]
            gateway4: 192.168.5.1
```

Thanks for helps.

Comment: The issue seem to be in routing. Have you checked the question below?

https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/93616/connect-pi-to-two-lans-using-usb-ethernet-adapter

Comment: Thanks for the link. I couldn't try it yet but it seems useful. It was our Sophos firewall issue. It is probably scanning the network for unknown devices with a period. When we plug the cable for obtaining ip it can connect to the internet but after a period it closes the unknown device's connection. We shared our internet from phones. The problem was gone. And it was a prototype now we are working on other parts of the device. When we apply it to pilot customers, I'll try. Thanks again.